# How to add a new .c file to Emacs source code

Tags: compilation, c

I've added my own `.c` file to Emacs `/src` directory as well as the following lines

```
emacs.o: ... file.c file.h
file.o: file.c
```

in `deps.mk`

I get `file.o` generated, but it is not linked when generating Emacs executable (at least that's what I see when I check presence of my function). Why?

In general, what actions should I undertake to add my `.c` file to Emacs executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting deps.mk:

```
## This file is included in src/Makefile if AUTO_DEPEND=no.\
```

So it's kind of a fallback file only used to give dependencies to make sure compilation ordering is right.  You want to look in `src/Makefile.in` instead where you should have no difficulty finding the variable that contains all the .o files we need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not in a build system but in Emacs itself.
In order to have a function defined with `DEFUN` available for a user you must not only define it but also write in your file:

```
void
syms_of_filename (void)
{
  defsubr (&Sfunction_name);
  ...
}
```

and call this function from `emacs.c`